# missing header in while transforming csv in nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv, stream, node-streams

I have csv file named "foo.csv" with the following data

```
A,B,C
asia,west,4
us,east,5
asia,north,4
```

I have wrote a function in nodejs with streams to process that csv which merges the first two column with `-`

```
import fs from "fs";
import {parse} from "csv-parse";
import through2 from "through2";

const myTransform = (row) => {
    return {
        A: row.A + "-" + row.B,
        B: row.C
    }
}

fs.createReadStream("input.csv", {objectMode: true})
    .pipe(parse({columns: true}))
    .pipe(through2.obj(function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        this.push(myTransform(chunk))
        callback()
    }))
    .pipe(through2.obj(function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        this.push(Object.values(chunk).join(",")+"\n")
        callback()
    }))
    .pipe(fs.WriteStream("output.csv"));
```

I get the output correctly in the `output.csv` as follows

```
asia-west,4
us-east,5
asia-north,4
```

which misses the header obviously, but how can I modify the above code to include the header ?

Moreover can I remove the usage of `throught2`, according to their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2#do-you-need-this), I think it's possible but I don't know how!!